# Scala UOM library

Tags: java, scala, units-of-measurement

I am looking for UOM library that can be added to a Scala project. A significant search lead me to find the flowing libraries, which do not seem to what I am looking for, because of reasons I will mention below:

[**squants**](https://github.com/garyKeorkunian/squants) - seems to be the most popular library out there, and the most well rounded units library I could find.

[**units**](https://github.com/KarolS/units)

[**scala-units**](https://github.com/bwkimmel/scala-units)

[**scunits**](https://github.com/gbeaty/scunits/tree/type-logic)

I might be wrong, but all these projects seem to have been abandoned, and I need something specific from the library I am looking for, which is the ability to extended it with new units of measurement at run-time, preferably from a file.
From the list above, the one that comes close to this requirement is the **scala-units**.

So my question is: Does anyone know of a SCALA, or Java UOM library that is well maintained (also with a permissive licence) that can be extended during run-time ?

Answer (score 1):

The Squants project has been adopted by the Typelevel community and development continues.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the more specialized ones for Scala could offer tighter integration (have not checked every of these) but for Java the official standard for UOM is [JSR 363](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=363): http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/

I know of at least one scientific institution using it with Scala already. For Groovy we offer official bindings, just a matter of time before Scala also joins, happy to have someone contribute where there are use cases.